# What is curl and how to use it with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I Can not understand the purpose and use case of curl. 
what it is meant to be doing?

There is this command that i saw in a tutorial and i don't know how it is working

```
curl -d 'hello' http://localhost:8080
```

we are passing the hello string to the server as a request and can't we do that in browser, if we can , can you please explain how to write the same thing in the browser

Comment: _"please explain how to write the same thing in the browser"_: what do you mean?

Comment: like in the command we have passed 'hello' string to the URL.

Can't we do the same thing using the URL in the browser,
like hitting this URL

http://localhost:8080/hello                            ?????

Comment: Your question title says "nodejs" but then you ask "in the browser" — which do you mean?

Comment: Did you do even the most basic Google search on curl?  If you did and thus you already know what this command line is supposed to do, then ask a much more specific question about what exactly you don't understand.  If you didn't, then that should be your first step before posting here.  We aren't here to answer broad questions that are explained already with simple Google searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl is used to programatically make a web request - with all sorts of options like following 301 links, sending post information, verifying SSL.

manually using the browser is manual and cannot be added to any script... JavaScript, PHP, etc

the -d option is for sending post information - manaully you can make a form to post this, or maybe use a browser plugin / extension to do that like tamperdata

Comment: If i would like to do the same request using the browser, what would it look like.

Answer (score -2):

The most basic CURL request:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

is exactly the same as typing http://localhost:8080 in your browser. Your browser address bar places GET requests, which is the default mode in curl as well.

HTTP has different request methods (the most well known are GET, POST, PUT and DELETE, but there are more). You can define the request method with curl by using a parameter -X followed by the request method:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080
```

This is what a PUT request (without data) looks like.

However, what you are doing is adding data to the request using the -d parameter. This sets the CURL request method to POST. If you want to make POST requests in your browser, it's best to install an add-on like 'Simple REST Client' for Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-rest-client/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

Comment: Why the two down votes? Am I saying something stupid?

Comment: Some people downvote any answer to poor questions.

Comment: Well, we're here to help right..?

Comment: Long story short, SO is flooded with low-quality questions, and answering them encourages asking them.

Comment: May i know how is this a low-quality question, so that i could be careful next time